# Loading txt file in Unity. It works on the PC, but not on the mobile phone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is such a code that I get text from a file and look for a match with word in it. When checking on a PC, everything works, as well as during debugging, and when compiling, the apk apparently does not see the files

```
 void Start()
        {
            words = (TextAsset[])Resources.LoadAll<TextAsset>("Library");
          } 

public bool checkWord(int count)
    {
        if (count >= 3)
        {


            string all = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(words[count - 3].bytes);
            String[] library = all.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            for (int i = 0; i < library.Length; i++)
            {
                int result = String.Compare(library[i], word);
                if (result == 0)
                {

                    return true;

                }


            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Files at Resources/Library

Comment: Maybe related https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-problem-with-resources-load.325590 ... Your title is a bit misleading since you not using the `File` library .. you should probably rephrase that

Comment: In general checkout [The Resources folder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BestPracticeUnderstandingPerformanceInUnity6.html) and also [Assets, Resources and AssetBundles - Best Practises](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7) where it explicitly states **Don't use it** ;)

Answer (score 1):

On android, your Unity files/resources are not just in the filesystem as on PC, they are packaged into the .apk and compressed. Iirc you can load them using the WWW class like this:

```
 static IEnumerator extractFileFromAPK(string from, string targetDir)       //read a file from [from] and save it into targetDir (keeping its original name) 
    { 

        byte[] result = null;

        if (from.Contains("://"))       //this will be the fileformat if it is inside the apk so you must read it from a jar://file
        {
            WWW www = new WWW(from);
            yield return www;
            result = www.bytes;
        }
        else
            result = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(from);//windows  
File.WriteAllBytes(System.IO.Path.Combine(targetDir,"whatevername.txt"), result);
}
```

Comment: You should however rather use [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html) instead of the **obsolete** [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html)

Comment: I do not fully understand what to write in the parameters and where the file is saved in the last line, how to access this file

Comment: i edited it to use the targetDir input string, you should be able to use this function to export things from the Resources folder in the apk to the normal persistentData where you can access it as usual

Comment: to access to file I must write "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/3.txt" at parameters ?
(if i write  File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "3.txt"), result); before)

Comment: I think the jar:file: might already be in the Application.dataPath, I recommend making a debug build where you just show the datapath on the UI so you can get an idea whats going on, thats how i did it, but that was more than 3 months ago so i cant tell you the exact process.

Btw, you might have to put assets that you want to load manually into the resources folder, in which case you can use Application.streamingAssetsPath. 
You could probably also get more generalised code snippets from here:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1231211/how-to-get-resources-filepath-on-android-device.html

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, you can't just run c# programs on android.
your code looks good, try to find out if there is any problem with your android compiler / apk maker on the PC. 
Android apps may cause a lot of problems with permissions, Are you sure you`ve got the permission to access files?

Comment: Since the question is tagged `unity3d` I'm pretty sure OP builds it to an Android apk before executing it on an Android device ... ;)